# Editing the same post twice in First Posts or Late Answers takes me out of the queue

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

On a site where I have less than 2k reputation, I suggested an edit to a post in the First Posts or Late Answers queue. The first time I click the Edit button under the post and then save my edits, everything works as it should. But then after I've submitted my edit, I noticed that I missed something in my edit. Then I clicked on the Edit button again to edit the things I've missed. When I clicked Save Edits again, it took me out of the review queue to the question page.

I also tested this on a site where I have more than 2k reputation, and everything works fine there.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Review First Posts or Late Answers on a site where you have less than 2k reputation
2. Suggest an edit to the post and submit your edit by clicking the Save Edits button
3. Click the Edit button again on the same post after submitting the edit
4. Do some more changes to your edit and click the Save Edits button again
5. You will find yourself on the question page outside of the review queue