# Do auto-generated 'Possible duplicate' comments count towards the Just Jesting hat?

Tags: support, comments, duplicate-questions, winter-bash-2017

The [Just Jesting](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/just-jesting) hat is earned by

> post[ing] 10 comments that each earn an upvote

[image]

Whenever I'm the first one to vote to close or flag a question as a duplicate, a comment is automatically generated: "Possible duplicate of $anotherQuestion.". This comment is also upvoted automatically if somebody else votes to close or flags the question as a duplicate (of the same question that I chose).

Do these automatic comments/upvotes count towards the Just Jesting hat or not? If they do, how about comments which were *deleted* because the duplicate was confirmed (i.e. the question was closed as a duplicate)?

As Sonic notes in the comments, an identical situation happens for comments generated by choosing/typing custom off-topic reasons.

Comment: Do comments posted from off-topic closures count as well? Those are also automatically upvoted when someone else chooses the same close reason.

Comment: Yeah, it'd be good to know as well, but I suppose (by invoking the KISS principle) those are handled the same way.

Comment: Just curious: why did you put a dollar sign in front of "anotherQuestion"? I saw someone else do the same thing [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360772/4284627) yesterday.

Comment: I think that was about translations. The dollar sign indicates a parameter which can be inserted, in this case the other question title. @donald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: probably not.

---

I just (pun intended) got the [Just Jesting hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel#winter-bash), but I have only [7 upvoted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel?tab=activity&sort=comments) which were posted during Winter Bash:

- [Access To a Review Queue I can't do anything with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304951/access-to-a-review-queue-i-cant-do-anything-with#comment991286_304951)
- [Winter Bash: Common Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304804/winter-bash-common-hats/304805#comment991193_304805)
- [Trying to get the Mother of Dragons secret hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304917/trying-to-get-the-mother-of-dragons-secret-hat/304918#comment991180_304918)
- [Why is a "reputation" required to ask a question about Windows 10?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304768/why-is-a-reputation-required-to-ask-a-question-about-windows-10/304769#comment990957_304769)
- [Winter Bash 2017 hatymology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304401/winter-bash-2017-hatymology/304402#comment989616_304402)
- [Winter Bash 2017 hatymology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304401/winter-bash-2017-hatymology#comment989460_304401)
- [Winter Bash 2017 hatymology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304401/winter-bash-2017-hatymology/304402#comment989503_304402)

That means deleted comments must count as well (just like they do for e.g. the Commentator badge). However, during Winter Bash, the following 9 questions were closed as duplicates, where I was the first to vote, so my autogenerated comment was upvoted:

- [Cannot add bounty to question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304931/295232)
- [Can we someday wear multiple hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304930/295232)
- [Can we have a tool to create red freehand circles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304852/295232)
- [I earned 11 hats, why don't I get the "The Milliner hat"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304709/295232)
- [You can't edit this post message is not showing in first post review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304676/295232)
- [Unexpectedly removed from a SE. How to enquire for the reasons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304668/295232)
- [What happens if a fifth person chooses a different reason to close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32700/295232)
- [Editing the same post twice in First Posts or Late Answers takes me out of the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304487/295232)
- [Review alert is over-eager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304438/295232)

If autogenerated/auto-upvoted comments would count, I would already have received the hat a few days ago.