# You can't edit this post message is not showing in first post review

Tags: feature-request, edits

I was doing **First Post Review**. When I clicked on the `edit`, it just doing nothing, I thought the script is not loaded, so I reloaded the page, so I checked other options `share` and `flag`, all are working.
Then I open the separate page for this. And then tried to `edit` the post, so it shows the following message:

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed

[image]

Why is this feature not set to `Review First Post` to show this message?

Comment: I think it's about time they fix this bug. It was first reported 5 months ago and duplicates reporting it get posted on a regular basis.

Comment: @DonaldDuck that's not a factor. If the bug is not critical, it usually take years until they even notice.