# I have earned 11 hats. Why don't I get the "The Milliner hat"?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

I have already earned 11 hats--10 on Stack Overflow and one here on meta.stackexchange.

But I still haven't got The Milliner hat, which says "collect 11 hats". Is it required to get all of them on one site?

[image: The Milliner]

Comment: @rene then the Hat description should be changed, no?

Comment: Why? Everything is per-site. Why suddenly hats aren't?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I thought it is a common celebration, so what about  **Brunhilde** which say (earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.) :)

Comment: So that one is very specific it spans sites, other don't.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickHofman, It's my bad I don't understand it correctly

Comment: Don't worry. We are here to help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to earn all 11 on the same site.  Next time you get a hat on SO, you'll get The Milliner.