# Is Fashionable hat for all questions during winter bash in all sites?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

The title is basically my question. Is Fashionable for views on all questions asked during Winter Bash on all sites or on just one site?

It has an explanation of:

> get over 9,000 combined total views on all questions that you asked during Winter Bash

But that doesn't get me anywhere with what I am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All hats have implicit requirements, one being that unless stated otherwise **the trigger counts only one site**.

That is why we get "why did I not get the hat" every year it runs [2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211984/278094) [2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245265/278094) [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288700/278094) [2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304709/278094)

Other hats this year that mean "do X on one site" are: Rep Hunter, Werewolf Hunter, Just Jesting, The Milliner, and Propel Thyself.

The only hats that have ever counted cross sites are Eliza Doolots, Running Ragged, and Brunhilde.