# Are hats different every Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Looking through a site with all competitions ever held, I noticed that every year, hats are different.
Is there any basic hats that don't change? I just wanted to write(not a question, just for me) how to earn every hat, but now I hesitate.
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they used to be **totally** different *every year* until last year.

Last year, it was [Winter Bash's 6th anniversary](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/?cb=1) so some hats were reused:

> But not just any hats: in celebration of the 6th anniversary of Winter Bash¹, some of the most beloved hats from years past will make their triumphant returns to the Winter Bash stage for a repeat performance. We’ve switched up the triggers to ensure hours of hat-gatherin’ fun. (And if you poke around, you might find a few newcomers waiting in the wings to be discovered, too!)

And on [last year's hat post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats), it's noted which were the hats reused.

---

I guess they continued the tradition this year and a ton of past hats was again reused.

There are also new hats, some of which are below.

[image: Glasses With A Number On Top] <sup>(used last year too, but with "2018")</sup>

[image: It Ain’t Easy Being Cheesy]
[image: Six-Cornered Hat]
[image: Peacekeeper]
[image: Rep Hunter]
[image: SO Goes Flapper]
[image: Team Player]
[image: Still Fresh]
[image: Top(bar) Hat]
[image: Freehand Circle]
[image: Member of The Hand]
[image: Retro Fan]
[image: The Merlin]
[image: Rubber Ducky]
[image: Clean-Up Duty]
[image: Propel Thyself]

---

Comment: True but also worth to mention many triggers have changed for hats with same name.

Answer (score 6):

The set of hats changes every year.  That's part of the fun -- to see what new ideas they come up with each time.  This year, some of the new hats were based on suggestions from the community in a contest held last year.  (My contest entry led to one of them.)

Some hats or hat triggers do repeat, not necessarily every year.  [Winter Bash: Common Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304804/winter-bash-common-hats) lists these repeated hats.

Each year there is a post describing how to earn that year's hats.  See, for example, [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319838/winter-bash-2018-hat-list).  If you want to compile this information for yourself, look up these posts for each year (if "hat list" doesn't find them all, try the tags).