# Which Winter Bash hats were reused in past years?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

A lot of the Winter Bash hats look really familiar to me! An example being "Glasses With A Number On Top":

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Are hats reused from previous Winter Bashes? If so, which hats and when were they reused?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a list of all the hats that were used during multiple Winter Bashes. Reusing of past Winter Bash hats started in [2017](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/) and continued in [2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/).

Note that although a hat may have the same design and name in different Winter Bashes, the trigger to get it is often different. For a list of common triggers, see [Winter Bash: Common Triggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304804/winter-bash-common-triggers).

---

[image: 1]

**Arqade's Hat Dash – 2011**: Link's Hat
**2017**: Hero Of Time

---

[image: 2]

**Arqade's Hat Dash – 2011**: The Numismatic
**2017**: It’s-a me!
**2018**: It’s-a me!

---

[image: 33]

**Arqade's Hat Dash – 2011**: The Rep Cap
**2017**: Rep Cap

---

[image: 3]

**2012**: Brunhilde
**2017**: Brunhilde
**2018**: Brunhilde

---

[image: 4]

**2012**: Just Jesting
**2017**: Just Jesting

---

[image: 5]

**2012**: I Do Say
**2017**: Silencium
**2018**: Silencium

---

[image: 30]

**2012**: Tis the Season
**2017**: Red Hat With White Fur Trim
**2018**: Gonna Find Out

---

[image: 6]

**2013**: I See Your Point
**2017**: Foot of the Rainbow

---

[image: 7]

**2013**: Robocop
**2018**: Peacekeeper

---

[image: 8]

**2013**: Before It Was Cool
**2017**: Too Cool
**2018**: Scarf Ace

---

[image: 9]

**2013**: R-E-S-P-E-C-T
**2017**: Think!

---

[image: 31]

**2013**: L'chaim
**2017**: Row Of Many Candles

---

[image: 32]

**2013**: With Great Power…
**2017**: Ooh, Shiny!

---

[image: 10]

**2013**: The Milliner
**2017**: The Milliner

---

[image: 11]

**2014**: Werewolf Hunter
**2017**: Werewolf Hunter

---

[image: 12]

**2014**: 30 Minutes or Less
**2017**: Extra Toppings
**2018**: Pizza Hat

---

[image: 13]

**2014**: Red Baron
**2018**: Red Baron

---

[image: 14]

**2014**: Waffles
**2017**: Waffles
**2018**: Waffles

---

[image: 15]

**2015**: Every! Body! Gets! A Hat!
**2017**: And YOU Get A Hat!

---

[image: 16]

post an accepted answer that receives no other votes for 12 hours

**2015**: Explorer
**2017**: Explorer
**2018**: Explorer

---

[image: 17]

**2015**: Fan-hat-ic
**2017**: Fascinator

---

[image: 18]

**2015**: Amazing Grace
**2017**: IDENTIFICATION DIVISION
**2018**: IDENTIFICATION DIVISION

---

[image: 19]

**2015**: Do it Yourself
**2017**: I’ll Handle It
**2018**: I’ll Handle It

---

[image: 20]

**2015**: 007
**2018**: James Bond

---

[image: 21]

**2015**: Sun Wukong
**2018**: Sun Wukong

---

[image: 22]

**2016**: Trendsetter
**2017**: Fashionable

---

[image: 23]

**2016**: Like Clockwork
**2017**: Like Clockwork

---

[image: 24]

**2016**: Elementary
**2017**: Sherlock

---

[image: 25]

**2016**: Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it
**2017**: Taco Tuesday Any Day

---

[image: 26]

**2016**: The Hatter
**2017**: The Mad Hatter

---

[image: 27]

**2016**: This Is Fine
**2017**: This Is Fine

---

[image: 28]
[image: 29]

**2017**: Glasses With A Number On Top
**2018**: Glasses With A Number On Top

Comment: A description of how those hats where "winnable" the previous years could be a nice addition (especially for the waffle hat where it might help us understand how to have it this year)

Comment: @Noon Yep, that's at [Winter Bash: Common Triggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304804/winter-bash-common-triggers)