# Winter Bash 2021 Hat List  

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

[Winter Bash 2021](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/15/millinery-on-the-stack-join-us-for-winter-summer-bash-2021/) has started and the hats are listed below.

As always, there are only two answers: one for the secret hats, and one for the regular hats. The secret hat list will be updated as we learn them.

*Please, only edit the secret hat answer with **definitive and correct triggers**. This is not the place to post guesses.* Winter Bash is a fun event, so secret hat triggers should be put behind spoilers (use the `>!` markup) in order to not to spoil the fun for those users who want to discover the triggers themselves.

If you'd like to discuss Winter Bash, hats or just have a question about it please come over to the [Winter Bash 2021 chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132350/winter-bash-2021).

Please keep the comments here clean. As always, comments are not meant for discussion, conversation, "I just got hat X", etc. use the [Winter Bash 2021 chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132350/winter-bash-2021) for that (comments may be cleaned up without further notice).

Here are the hats from previous years:

- [Winter Bash 2020 hat list 👒 🎩](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357915)
- [❄️ Winter Bash 2019 Hat list ❄️](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339891)
- [Winter Bash 2018 Hat list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319838)
- [Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304340)
- [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271)
- [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789)
- [Winter Bash 2014 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245170)
- [Winter Bash 2013 Secret Hats](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/01/03/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)

Comment: Hat or no hats, fun or no fun, please don't make me have to see an emoji.

Comment: Given the Covid situation, we should have had a Mask List this time around.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

## Secret hats for Winter Bash 2021

**Thought Bubble**

[image: Thought Bubble]

Trigger:

> Have a conversation in chat: at least 5 distinct blocks of messages [sent] in chat in one room [in] a day ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59911779#59911779))

---

**Spotting Scope**

[image: Spotting Scope]

Trigger: Unknown

---

**Detective**

[image: Detective]

Trigger:

> Earn 3 secret hats on a specific site ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59891440#59891440))

---

**Monologue**

[image: Monologue]

Trigger:

> Ask a positively scored question that gets answered ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59906124#59906124))

---

**Dialogue**

[image: Dialogue]

> Comment under an answer to your own question - the question must have a positive score ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59910078#59910078)).

---

**Trialogue**

[image: Trialogue]

Trigger:

> Answer gets edited after commenting under an answer to your own question - the question must have a positive score ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59922860#59922860))

---

**Quadalogue**

[image: Quadalogue]

Trigger:

> Quadalogue: A asks a positive score question, B answers the question, A and C comment under the answer, and B edits the answer and A accepts that answer. ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60034289#60034289)). All [...]logue hats are given to question OP.

---

**Defender of the Unicorn**

[image: Defender of the Unicorn]

Trigger:

> 1. Post a question that later receives a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag on Meta Stack Exchange ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59899528#59899528))
>  2. Save [Sparkles the unicorn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374461/828089)

---

**E-pic**

[image: E-pic]

Trigger:

> Ask a question without the letter 'E' in the title. [Confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60050070#60050070). Letter 'O' for Ru.SO.

---

**One buried penny**

[image: One buried penny]

Trigger:

> Suggesting an edit(that gets approved) on a post that was inactive for one month. ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60014685#60014685))

---

**Two buried pennies**

[image: Two buried pennies]

Trigger:

> Suggesting an edit(that gets approved) on a post that was inactive for one month and that post receives an upvote (upvote by the editor won't trigger it). ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60014693#60014693))

---

**Three buried pennies**

[image: Three buried pennies]

Trigger:

> Edit a 1 month inactive question that gets an upvote (not by the editor) and receives a +3 score answer(not by the editor). ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60014713#60014713))

---

**Matryoshka**

[image: Matryoshka]

Trigger:

> Post a question of +5 score with >=5 positive answers ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59941822#59941822))

---

**Satellite view**

[image: Satellite view]

Trigger: Unknown

---

**Cleanup**

[image: Cleanup]

Trigger: Unknown

---

**Helping finger**

[image: Helping finger]

Trigger

> Post three positively scored comments under a user's first post ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/132350?m=59906273#59906273))

---

**Helping hand**

[image: Helping Hand]

Trigger:

> Post two positively scored comments under a user's first post and the OP edits the question after the comments ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59942178#59942178))

---

**Helping heart**

[image: Helping heart]

Trigger: Unknown

---

**Helping arm**

[image: Helping arm]

Trigger:

> Comment on a new user's first post, which the new user then edits, which later scores 2+ (not closed, reopened ok) ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59947287#59947287))

---

**Kitsune**

[image: Kitsune]

Trigger:

> Vote to reopen a question and answer it with a positive score once it is reopened ([confirmed by Slate](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59912467#59912467))

---

**Manual key**

[image: Manual Key]

Trigger:

> Copy something from the body of a post on a Meta site (MSE included). The question must be a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) ([confirmed by Catija](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59909909#59909909))

---

**Slow Trickle**

[image: Slow Trickle]

Trigger:

> Get upvotes on an answer or a question on 4 distinct days ([confirmed by Yaakov](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59954116#59954116))

Comment: If you do discover a trigger please do those that want to find them themselves the courtesy of posting them in a spoiler!

Comment: If anyone wants confirmation for a spoiler, [ping me in the WB2021 chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132350/winter-bash-2021)

Comment: **Manual Key**.  I think there might be other ways to earn this hat.  I did not even visit a `discussion` type question (I don't think).  I only visited this question and I don't think I copied anything from it.  However, I may have copied code from a different Stack Overflow question today.  I dunno.  Not sure!

Comment: Re: Kitsune, a positive score on "it"? That's ambiguous.  Which post is "it"? If the question was negative 3, how am I suppose to be responsible for its recovery? Am I meant to not try to help deeply negative posts? Hats that depend on upvotes can be very hard to reach in some communities/tags.

Comment: For "Quadalogue", the description mentions multiple users doing various things, but doesn't say which of them is eligible for that hat.

Comment: @khelwood The question OP.

Comment: @Wolgwang I don't need to know, but it should be in the description.

Comment: @YaakovEllis - The Bash is over but some secrets still remain. Would you be uncovering them?

Comment: @PM77-1 If I remember correctly, triggers that are still unknown are not revealed so that they can be used next year.

Answer (score 48):

## Regular hats for Winter Bash 2021

#### Clockwork

[image: Clockwork]

Description: Cast votes at regular times

Tip: Cast a vote in the same hour on seven consecutive days.

---

#### Tenacious

[image: Tenacious]

Description: Write a good self-answer to an old question

Tip: Answer your own question three or more days later with an answer of score five or greater.

---

#### Rep hunter

[image: Rep hunter]

Description: Write 10 good answers in one day

Tip: Write 10 positively-scored answers on open questions in one day.

---

#### Spotless

[image: Spotless]

Description: Write a perfect question the first time

Tip: No edits or flags on a positive, open question asked during Winterbash for one week.

---

#### Consensus

[image: Consensus]

Description: Have your reopen reviews validated

Tip: Complete eight consecutive reopen reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 25 on Stack Overflow.)

---

#### Rapport

[image: Rapport]

Description: Have your close reviews validated

Tip: Complete eight consecutive close reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 25 on Stack Overflow.)

---

#### Harmony

[image: Harmony]

Description: Have your suggested edit reviews validated

Tip: Complete eight consecutive suggested edit reviews, where the majority of voters agreed with you. Reviews without votes don't count! (Note: takes 25 on Stack Overflow.)

---

#### Hi5

[image: Hi5]

Description: Have five of your answers accepted in one day

Tip: Have five of your answers accepted by others in the same day.

---

#### Rep cap

[image: Rep cap]

Description: Hit the rep cap

Tip: Gain 200 reputation from votes or suggested edits in one day (hit the reputation cap).

---

#### Soapbox

[image: Soapbox]

Description: Start a good meta-discussion

Tip: Start any [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) question of score two or greater on any network Meta site (score eight or greater on MSO or MSE).

---

#### Plus 44

[image: Plus 44]

Description: Write a good answer to a good question

Tip: Answer a previously unanswered question of score four or greater with an answer of score four or greater.

---

#### I voted

[image: I voted]

Description: Vote anywhere

Tip: Upvote or downvote on any open question or answer.

---

#### Glare reducers

[image: Glare reducers]

Description: Try High Contrast or Dark Mode

Tip: Try out the new High Contrast or Dark Mode features. Only on Stack Overflow and its language specific sites where "Dark Mode" is an available setting.

---

#### Starfish

[image: Starfish]

Description: Write two well-liked comments

Tip: Post two comments of score five or greater.

---

#### Gem detector

[image: Gem detector]

Description: Cast 50 upvotes on questions that stay open

Tip: Cast 50 upvotes on questions when they are less than two days old, 95% of which are still open after four days.

---

#### Gem finder

[image: Gem finder]

Description: Cast 30 upvotes on questions that stay open

Tip: Cast 30 upvotes on questions when they are less than two days old, 90% of which are still open after four days.

---

#### Gem watcher

[image: Gem watcher]

Description: Cast 10 upvotes on questions that stay open

Tip: Cast 10 upvotes on questions less than two days old, 80% of which are still open after four days.

---

#### Sunrise

[image: Sunrise]

Description: Write a well-received first question

Tip: Ask a question that's well-received by the community on a site you haven't used before.

---

#### New moon

[image: New moon]

Description: Write a well-received question during the new moon

Tip: Ask a question at any time around the new moon (Jan 2 6:35 PM UTC +/- 12 hours).

---

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373006/223467, "Glare reducer" is only available on Stack Overflow (and its non-English counterparts). Should this be edited into the post?

Comment: it should be different -- https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/  no "perfect question the first time" Glorfindel.  :(

Comment: I can't even find the Dark Mode setting in the new layout.

Comment: @mickmackusa On Stack Overflow, go to your profile in the top right and press 'Settings' under your avatar next to 'Activity' to find dark mode

Comment: I hope someone got the Plus 44 reference. ^_^

Comment: @Vanny Polish notation?

Comment: @Wolgwang thank you for converting them to PNGs. I should make that part of my script to generate the initial version of the post ...

Comment: I earned Satellite View. Based on my activities (flagging spam across the sites as a Charcoal regular) and the associations I get, I speculate it's related to visiting multiple sites in the network.

Comment: Spotting Scope speculation (somewhat tongue in cheek): Tried to use search, gave up.

Comment: The Rapport hat, have your close reviews validated, what does it mean exactly? As I have done many close reviews between today and yesterday and still didn't get it.

Comment: @Peter I imagine you get that when a review you participated in reaches a consensus by having others review the same post and agree with you to close or leave open.

Comment: I earned One Buried Penny apparently for editing an old post. I edited one of my own and one by another user (who approved my edit suggestion because I don't have enough rep on that site) so it could be either of those two.

Comment: I have both One Burried Penny and Two Burried Pennies. I think the first is for getting one edited post approved and winning +2 points, and the 2nd is for getting a 2nd edited post approved and winning another +2 points. I edited several posts on Unix and Linux to finally break 1000 points there. [See my first +2 reputation 2 days ago, on 22 Dec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/114401/gabriel-staples?tab=reputation).

Comment: I just got the Spotting Scope, and I noticed it few minutes after editing a 8 months old post of mine (similarly to the Excavator badge).

Comment: I got spotting scope apparently after rolling back someone else's (recent) edits (vandalism) on their posts (while posts were deleted) (and flagged a moderator on one). This might be considered an edit, the rollback was via editing only the revision reason on the target version.

Comment: Experimentally, I edited another post of my own from 2017 on Unix&Linux but did not earn One Penny there. On Ask Ubuntu, I submitted an edit suggestion on somebody else's post from 2011 and had that approved; that earned me One Penny on Ask Ubuntu too. The remaining question I think is how old exactly the edited post has to be.

Comment: @tripleee One month (IMO) I tested it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69908181/subtract-from-m-and-s-with-ffmpeg?__=1629851482) ... Also I got the two burried pennies hat when someone upvoted it...

Comment: I got Spotting Scope the same moment I unlocked Gem watcher. I just added a brand new tag and used the search to add it to a couple old questions, so @tripleee could be right

Comment: I just got Spotting Scope; I edited both the Q&A of a 10-yr old question (my answer). It's the only real thing I did today aside from a lone close vote (no others) and some minor comments; haven't done much for about a week prior.

Comment: Community Bot has spotting scope on dba.se, which is interesting.  I see it has rejected a few reviews, as have I (I also have spotting scope), so perhaps the act of rejecting a review triggers the hat.