# Got Glare reducers on wrong sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

I just received Glare reducers on Server Fault when I tried it on Stack Overflow

[image]

Update: Got it on 8 more sites now. But not on SO.

Comment: Also got it on server fault and haven't visited the site in months.  And now on SU and webapps, also sites I barely visit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix is in place.

Due to bug, this was being awarded on every single site the user has an account, if they have dark mode set on SO. Hats awarded on non-SO sites have been removed.

This hat can only be awarded on SO or on one of the non-English SO sites.

Comment: But it's still not awarded on SO yet.

Comment: "All hats can be earned on any participating Stack Exchange site" - Winter Bash FAQ. Is it possible to earn this hat on a non-SO site?

Comment: @JoKing It seems like SO specific hat only.

Comment: Yeah, it will be SO-only (or the non-English SO sites). All the sites where dark mode is available.

Comment: I see the wrong hats were removed from my profile, but now the hat count is 1 even though I have no hats (had no other hats before this update). I guess this is just a caching issue?

Comment: Maybe rephrase that part in the FAQ then?

Comment: Ok, all illegetimate hats should be gone, and you should be getting this hat now for SO if you have dark-mode turned on.

Comment: @YaakovEllis But I still have Glare Reducers option on my profile on non-SO sites

Comment: @Minot enjoy it then. You can keep it on as long as you want, but once it is off, you cant get it back (on that site).

Comment: I got the hat on SO and SO en español, although I have not visited SO en español during Winter Bash. I don't know if that is intended.

Answer (score 2):

Not an official answer, but from what I've seen Dark Mode and High Contrast are only available on Stack Overflow. It seems that after enabling one of those settings, the hat will be awarded (annoyingly slowly) on all the sites you have accounts on.