# Show off your hats! (2021 edition)

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, fun, winter-bash-2021

Winter Bash 2021 [has just started](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372501/401803) and [lots of users already got a hat](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard).

So let's show those hats off here! I'm lacking creativity, so I'll just copy the same text from a [previous edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305135/401803):

> Post hats, hats, and more hats! Those that you're especially proud of, or that you simply look good in - all are welcome ;)

Answer (score 34):

Who knew? Even narwhals can do scuba diving! Just comes do show that anyone can do anything :)

[image]

Mr.Narwhal dreams of having a
private island, despite the fact he couldn't live on land

[image]

So, he's planning to disgiuse as a seal with style :D

[image]

He searched on the web to find a island, he settled for Rarotonga. An island not to far from his homeland.

[image]

And he lived happily ever after! Until he actually realised he couldn't stay on land forever :|

Comment: Narwhal looks very cute with hats :)

Answer (score 20):

It matches the background of my avatar. 8)

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Combination!

[image]

Comment: A mad hatter...

Answer (score 17):

My trusty dog is back!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17):

Hats are hard to come by this year, so I guess I'll just go snorkeling in the snow...
[image]

Oh, and that hat is the cordovan from last year, I just made it a permanent part of my profile picture, so no need to go hunting for it.

Answer (score 17):

Anyone wants something to eat?

Got nice treats for Holidays

[image]

Comment: Why would you treat your Helpful Finger that way!? (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻

Comment: @Ollie it's helpful because it helps me finding treasures in my nose

Comment: What have you found so far? ;)

Comment: @Ollie I'm French, so, French food : Snails and Oysters

Answer (score 16):

Putting my new (and current favorite hat) Spotting Scope to good use:

[image]

---

<s>The Yule Ball</s> Winter Bash is a time for controlled frivolity (especially for the unicorns)

[image]

Comment: The Photoshop on that last one isn't the greatest...

Answer (score 16):

**Bat** turned detective **Rat** !

[image]

---

One of the rarest hat!

[image]

---

Coming out of the [cave](https://i.gifer.com/5k9W.gif) .

[image]

---

A low rep user's dream hat!

[image]

---

Fits

[image]

Answer (score 15):

**"Good morning everyone and welcome to 'Science and Society'. I'm Dr. Sheldon Cooper, BS, MS, MA, Ph.D., and ScD. OMG, right?"**

[image]

**"Bazinga"**

[image]

**"I'm Not Crazy. My Mother Had Me Tested."**

[image]

**"I'm exceedingly smart. I graduated college at fourteen. While my brother was getting an STD, I was getting a Ph.D."**

[image]

**"Scissors Cuts Paper. Paper Covers Rock. Rock Crushes Lizard."**

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I didn't see Helping Arm in any of the answers, and no, I have no idea how I got it.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

It's time to swim!

[image]

That's my face:

[image]

Nice place for Hide and Seek:

[image]

Comment: *drowning.....*

Answer (score 13):

Yep, mountains can vote...

[image]

---

Matryoshka is not a good climber:

[image]

---

Underwater mountain?

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Unless anyone's got any bright ideas, I guess I'll have to give up the cigars...

[image]

---

Keep at least one eye on your enemies...

[image]

Answer (score 13):

"The dream of sand and water"

[image]

---

"I guess I could actually try"

[image]

---

"What do you mean, this is not a mane ornament?"

[image]

---

"But friendship carries on through the ages..."

[image]

---

"Rarity vision, Activate!"

[image]

---

"Gotcha"
[image]

---

"No, I didn't stole Twily's telescope"

[image]

---

"I doubt this count as a Celestia's cosplay, right?"

[image]

(alternate title: "What did this cost to you? Everything" since I had to create another new account. Only to delete it afterwards...)

---

"Posting a qustion about My Littl Pony: Frindship is Magic without using a spcific lttr is vry asy and won't rquir any chat at all..."

[image]

> yes, the picture title is indeed intended to look that way since it is part of the joke.

Comment: prediction of the day: the one who serial downvoted all answers here will probably see their vote reverted...

Comment: Whoops! I realized that I have misread your comment. I thought you meant the upvotes were serial, as I didn't notice the "down" in your comment. Sorry about that!

Comment: @AnnofProgrammingGables There must be an user that has the habit to mass downvote post that are about fun, staff announcements and similar things. I have noticed multiple times question like this receiving a downvote on every single answer in quick succession.

Comment: Who is in the avatar?

Comment: @Wolgwang that would be Fluttershy.

Comment: Ah! Very Cute 

Comment: @Wolgwang I suppose I could switch to the [human version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV3py.jpg)... maybe after WB is over.

Answer (score 13):

A lot of trivial knowledge richer:

[image]

---

Something South Park-y about this.

[image]

---

"*WAAAAAAAAAALL-E*"

[image]

---

With a little imagination this is a ridiculous racing helmet:

[image]

---

Let me just take this opportunity to compliment the fact that hats can stick out of the frame.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Excellent - another one that fits my avatar perfectly - even down to the colour scheme :-)

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I feel so fancy! :D Happy Winter Bash everyone~

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Not quite sure what to do with these ...

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Wear your hats as **large** as you can everyone! This is how we raise awareness about Winter Bash!

[image]

[image]

These hats are also cool, but I prefer big hats so I'm using the above ones in my profile :)

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 10):

A bit hidden I am... **but I voted!**

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Magic hat...

[image: Magic hat]

Comment: _BLEEEEOOOORPHHHHH!!!!!_

Comment: @Vikki That's what happens when you eat too much charcoal ;)

Answer (score 9):

Solar Satellite

[image: Solar Satellite]

Nothing like a cool waterfall to take some of the heat

[image: Waterfall]

Defender of the unicorn

[image: Defender of the unicorn]

Answer (score 9):

Maybe I should banish [Babbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Babbage) to some remote island..

[image]

..since wearing hats and informatics isn't purely a male domain..

[image]

..so I can grasp a glimps of the universe of mathematics..

[image]

..and dive into the depths of analytic computations.

[image]

Comment: Don't banish Babbage, how is he going to finish building that machine?

Comment: Is she Ada Lovelace?

Comment: @Cid Yes well spotted- extra points if you can decode the binary overlay in my profile pic ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix yes I can. No I won't. I'm too lazy :p

Comment: When I speak with female programmers who underestimate themselves (as programmer) because of some BS gender things that have been told to her, I tell them to do researches about the very first programmer, Ada Lovelace

Comment: @Cid _"No I won't"_ That's what I thought - looking at your profile-pic you still busy hunting for treasures ;)

Comment: @Cid _"I tell them to do researches about the very first programmer, Ada Lovelace"_ A very valid argument and a good point - that's nice of you to encourage female programmers!

Comment: [Good appetite](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/d6/83/a1/d683a19469d3efd374cead96f66c3f36.jpg)

Comment: @Cid One should [use the middle-finger](https://tubestatic.orf.at/static/images/site/tube/20190727/maaaad.5904172.jpg) to go treasure hunting..

Comment: @iLuvLogix [Well...](http://h16free.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/why-not-both-meme.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

Be careful when copying:

[image: White Tiger chomping on The Key™]

Answer (score 7):

After the [Glare reducers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373006/182734) bug fix, here comes my first hat which aligned well with Victor (from Love, Victor):

[image]

Some other hats I liked on Victor are:

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Bounty awarded for most hats on MSE.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

That's uh, a lot of hats.

Answer (score 7):

I may look cool on the outside, but you don't know what I'm secretly thinking about:
[image: A moai-shaped flowerpot with a layer of snow on top and a thought bubble with a deserted island with a palm tree]

The ice caps aren't melting, they said. "Better safe than sorry" is my approach:

[image: A moai-shaped flowerpot with a layer of snow on top and a pair of goggles]

Just what I feared: the icecaps are melting and the slow trickle is gradually turning into a deluge:

[image: A moai-shaped flowerpot with some sort of green cap from which water is pouring down on both sides of the face]

Comment: I see danger!...

Answer (score 7):

it's getting really hot in here, with all that hats and masks

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Finally a hat that really makes sense in a mountain:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

"*If you weren't a mountain, what would you like to be?*"

[image]

Comment: A hat, obviously ;)

Answer (score 6):

snorkeling with a mask on :)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I look good with Kitsune:

[image]

> Don't mess with this snail!!!

Answer (score 6):

The Glare Reducers really make the Rorschach inkblot look like it has a face.

[image: Rorschach inkblot with Glare Reducers]

Comment: When I first saw, it looked like a wolf. Only after reading the description I realized it is a Rorschach inkblot :-)

Answer (score 6):

## TheScubaDivingNaruto

[image]

## TheBigHatNaruto

[image]

Answer (score 6):

My Helpful Fingers are helpfully copy/pasting of their own accord:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It even kind of looks like my mouth is molded around the mouthpiece of the snorkel!

[image]

Answer (score 5):

At MSE we think big:

[image: Thought Bubble hat]

Answer (score 5):

Distinguished.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The sun is rising behind my snail!

[image]

A "snail-riser".

Comment: it's a "snail-riser"

Comment: @Vickel Lol! haha

Answer (score 5):

I'm watching YOUR gems :)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

At least it looks like a strap.

[image: my hat]

Answer (score 5):

### Starfish

I love this one, it’s like “King Cthulhu” now.

[image: Cthulhu with seashell tiara!]

Or, well more like “Cthulhu with matching underwater tiara,” which just makes the winter holidays absolutely stunning!!

Answer (score 5):

Blub blub!

[image: Avatar of a skeleton wearing a scuba mask]

Answer (score 5):

I'm a *Detective* now

[image: Detective]

and I'm having *Thought bubbles* "About you"

[image: Thought bubble]

in perfect *Harmony*

[image: Harmony]

with an open *Consensus*

[image: Consensus]

and have a good *Rapport* now

[image: Rapport]

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>KEKE</kbd> <kbd>IS</kbd> <kbd>HOLMES</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I wish it would be easier to get hats this year. At least my turtle looks nice with Glare Reducers hat!

[image]

And this is Spotting Scope:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly partial to the Gem Finder "hat" at the moment:

[image: Gem Finder Smile]

Comment: If you manage to find the ♦ gem I'll give you a 100-reputation bounty ;)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Slow Trickle on nobody]

This hat looks better when inverted.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know cats could vote!

[image: cat and a hat]

Fancy hat:

[image]

I didn't know cats could scuba dive:

[image: cat scuba diving]

Answer (score 4):

***Hi5*** to everyone out there,

[image: Hi5]

Definitely *I voted*,

[image: I_Voted]

putting on the *Glare Reducers*

[image: Glare Reducers]

and sporting the *Spotting Scope*

[image: Spotting_Scope]

with a *Satellite View*

[image: Satellite view]

Answer (score 4):

Too cute

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am a strong snail:

[image]

Or you @#$%&!:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My name is dippas...erhh...Sherlock Holmes

[image: SS]

Ready for a scuba dive

[image: SS]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

the unicorn is safe now!

[image]

Comment: Well done!  I *still* haven't done it...

Comment: go for it @Ollie, it's great fun to crack the puzzle(s)

Answer (score 4):

[**2022 in spaceflight**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_in_spaceflight)

[image: satellite and telescope hats]

Answer (score 4):

**Scuba Diver**

[image]

**Stack Overlow Mayor :)**

[image]

**Me after seeing a code block within a Stack Overflow answer**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I was pretty happy with this satellite wandering around the colors of my avatar :-)

[image: A satellite orbiting a generally plus-shaped geometric rainbow pattern]

Answer (score 3):

Rainbow head:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Woohooo!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What the Bear said, I got a hat.

[image: Show off your hats! (2020 Edition)]

Answer (score 3):

Universal_learner voted

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: I voted]

I can exclusively confirm that Pikachu voted.

Answer (score 3):

it's hot where I come from

[image]

I'm ready for Christmas dinner, all soaped up :)

[image]

What a X-mas present!

[image]

X-mas seen from space

[image]

Comment: I've had some of my hat posts deleted, due to *"you really don't need to post separate answers for every single hat. You'll notice other users posted just a few of their favorites in one answer... You're kind of flooding the question with them which makes it harder for others to get visibility.*" I'm sorry for that. So I have the last ones compiled here. I still don't know why posting one hat each time, gets you in conflict with the theme of this post: *Post hats, hats, and more hats! Those that you're especially proud of, or that you simply look good in - **all are welcome** ;)*

Comment: That might need to be brought up into discussion later, but in general, I agree with "fewer answers".  3 answers containing 5 hats each might be better than 14 posts with 1 hat each.  I've posted two or three answers; if I get a significant number of extra hats (*when*!), I'll post another, then just edit in extra pictures.  I don't think it's that big of a thing, though.  Happy Bashing!

Comment: same to you (Happy Bashing) @Ollie, rules need to be established before, and not during an event. I will bring this up after January 5th

Answer (score 3):

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| The **Helping Finger** 'hat' is especially appropriate for Minsky | [Reference (from [Fargo season 3's animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=It3MISMvR2I): "*I can help!*")] |

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| [There's Treasure Everywhere](https://calvinandhobbes.fandom.com/wiki/There%27s_Treasure_Everywhere) | "*One needs to cover their face in order to hold the pipe*" |

Answer (score 2):

I wear stuff differently.

Proof:

[image]

A good scarf.

Answer (score 2):

This old bike got a long-needed **mouth of fresh air**.

[image: Bike with Glare reducers hat]

And then it finally got the buried **treasure**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was about time!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Monologue Hat]

This is evidently one of the secret hats. I don't know what I did to deserve this.