# Name blocked by hat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Part of a name gets blocked by the hat when it is in a certain position.

[image: blocked name]

And here, the *entire* username is blocked by the hat...

[image: worldbuilding hat blocked]

Maybe this could be fixed by having the username text displaying over the image of the hat?

Comment: this is a feature

Comment: If block, move hat.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it goes below [the activity button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzfjB.png)

Comment: [Things like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313576) [happen every year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403735); it's part of the fun of hats!

Answer (score 11):

I believe this can only happen if the user specifically adjusts their hat to do it - it won't happen by default.  And that's only if they opt-in to wearing the hat in the first place.

If someone wants to mutilate their avatar in such a way, the system should allow it.

Comment: [Why is @KimHolder's hat bigger than mine?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/932/12102)

Answer (score 10):

This is a byproduct of the flexibility that we give to users in terms of hat placement (I think that it comes up every year). Calling it a feature and moving on.

Comment: The text for "Profile" and "Activity" [do indeed appear above the hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373061/377214), if it's positioned that way. Is that a bug?