# Gregorio Y. Zara hat covers up username in chat

Tags: bug, design, chat, winter-bash, winter-bash-2022

The user [Panda](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/327561/panda) currently wears the Gregorio Y. Zara hat. But, now in chat, his username is covered up:

[image]

When a user has multiple messages in a row, their username is aligned under the profile image.

But now, for Panda, his username is covered up due to the Gregorio Y. Zara hat's design.

It seems that the hat design isn't transparent, it is white in the bottom, so it can cover up the other parts of your profile image. But for chat, it also covers up the username.

Can it be fixed?

Comment: All part of the plan! 

Comment: This is something that's a foreseeable consequence of how this, or any hat, can be sized and positioned. While the specifics of this hat might make it surprising, it's clear that the hat does overlay content both above and below the hat's rectangle. The user can position it such that those overlays are above and below the avatar, just like any hat can extend beyond the bounds of the avatar – such as your, which partially obscures your username. So, this doesn't look like a bug to me, just a normal consequence of hats can be positioned by the user.

Comment: @Panda The name of the hat is "Gregorio Y. Zara", who is the inventor of videophone. It seems quite likely that fill above and below the box is intended to make the hat cause the avatar to appear letterboxed in order to imply the avatar is in a video, rather than that it's just a box. Overall, this appears to be [tag:status-bydesign] to me. Note: while wide video formats are more familiar to people at this time, video at the time of the invention would have had an aspect ratio of 4:3, or close to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gregorio Y. Zara hat indeed has a white background, making it look odd, especially when using dark mode.

> [image]

> [image]

---

The extra whitespaces at the top and bottom of the hat appear to be caused by the SVG having a white background (due to an additional `fill="#fff"`).

```
<svg width="192" height="192" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 192 192" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="rotate(0 3.14 2.18) translate(28.644989790510152 28.644989790510152) scale(1.0544815688374145)">
        <g clip-path="url(#b)">
            <g clip-path="url(#a)">
                <g clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <path d="M128 0H0V128H128V0ZM121 25H7V104H121V25Z" fill="#fff"></path>
                                                                       ^caused by this
```

The white background can be removed by editing out `fill="#fff"` from the line `<path d="M128 0H0V128H128V0ZM121 25H7V104H121V25Z" fill="#fff"></path>`. See my test on a black background below.

> [image]

None of the other Winter Bash hats has such a white background, see the image below for a comparison.

> [image]

Comment: Nice find! Upvoted and accepted.

Comment: [Blocking the name is considered a feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374077/269301).

Comment: This is a non-issue. Just don't make the hat so big and it won't hide anything. Simple as that.

Comment: While you have identified what causes this, I think it's quite likely that the `fill="#fff"` is intended in order to make the hat cause the avatar appear more like it's in a video, rather than that it's just got a box. The person who the hat is named after is the inventor of the first two-way videophone, so having the hat make the avatar appear that it's in a video is probably the intent of this hat. Note: while the wide video format is more familiar to people at this time, video at the time of the invention would have been in the 4:3 format, or close to it.

Comment: @Makyen Sounds reasonable and I'm assured, it is in fact, [intentional](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62639518#62639518).

Comment: How do you access the code for the file, edit the file to change the design of the hat and make it appear on a profile? Otherwise, this you maybe used a software to preview the hat’s edited design.

Comment: @TymaGaidash https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/hat/4028439.svg?v=d301bf385042