# The Stack Overflow leaderboard hats run off the side of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

Android v.11 Galaxy XCover Pro, with Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64 in Desktop view (it doesn't give me the option for "Full Site").

The [Stack Overflow leaderboard](https://winterbash2021.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/stackoverflow.com) hats run off the side of the page when - depending on the length of the user's name - they get to 8.
[image]

As there are up to [38 hats to be won](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372999/winter-bash-2021-hat-list) it won't be possible to see them all.

Is there any scope for returning them on to successive lines instead?

Comment: Similar issue with LaTeX on main sites.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGVRg.jpg)

Comment: If the answer solved your problem please don't forget to [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just pushed a slight layout overhaul to make the leaderboards page more responsive. Hats should now wrap regardless of screen size, and items should look aligned regardless of content size. As a consequence, this overflowing (hehe) on smartphones should also be gone!

Thanks for reporting! Appreciate the help.

Comment: It looks good, thanks and Happy Christmas:)

Comment: Isn't [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YageB.png) too compact?