# "Defender of the Unicorn" hat, who found it with both triggers?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2021

The Defender of the Unicorn hat is a very special hat, since it has two
[triggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373001/):

- resolve the puzzle (save Sparkles)
- receive a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on a question

Since Winter Bash 2021 came to an end, who, or at least how many users, got both triggers?

Comment: User Dharman got both triggers, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374461/oh-no-can-you-find-our-unicorn#comment1248012_374461.

Comment: I did, you did too :)

Comment: Hi! In response to [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com//transcript/message/54244539#54244539): I'm sorry, but putting an email in my profile is something I don't want to do right now. Perhaps later, but the present, no. :( [See also my reponse to U12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374781/delete-uploaded-picture-in-profile-from-i-stack-imgur-com-hosting/374841#comment1259637_374841)

Comment: np @richardec , you can find mine somewhere in the transcript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a user was manually awarded the hat for posting something on meta that was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) and then successfully completed the quiz, we don't actually record anything (since the reward for successful completion is getting the hat, and they already have it). So I don't have any way to accurately answer this, other than to say that it is more than 0, and fewer than the number of [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) posts tagged with [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash) or [winter-bash-2021](/questions/tagged/winter-bash-2021) that were posted during WB this year.

Comment: I got the hat but don't recall doing a *quiz*. Are you, or anyone else, able to explain what / where it was, please? I'm a noob and don't fully understand SE jargon / colloquialisms.

Comment: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374082/818993) gave you the hat @Rick. A post related to Winter Bash that received [status-complete] tag.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Ahh, it's either / or! I get it now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yaakov, for taking time to look into this Q. I was hoping you had a query. Thanks for all your support, and also thanks to your team, WB2021 was great fun again!

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that regular users have no information about how hats are earned, just ***that*** they were earned. Someone from the development team may be able to tell you stats on how many people earned the hat via route 1 versus via route 2, but I'm not sure if it's worth their valuable time which could be spent on other development projects.

I'd like to add that I got the "Defender of the Unicorn" hat without doing either of those two things mentioned. I discovered that there was a bug in the awarding of one of the hats, and communicated my concerns in the Winter Bash 2021 chatroom. It turned out that there actually was in fact a bug, which then got fixed and I was deemed to have done the "equivalent" of having asked a question that got the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, so I was awarded the hat manually. There's therefore *technically* at least three different ways to get that hat (though you can just group what happened with me into your second listed category).

Comment: "other development projects" - like more hats!