# Trying to get the Mother of Dragons secret hat

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

I think that I have to ask my a question on a Stack Exchange site for 3 days with a score of +3. I was wondering if I could get some help on the details of this hat.

I see that I have to:

> Make your first post of a class (question or answer) on a SE site and get a score of 3 or more lasting 3 days.

But I'm not sure what it means by "Make your first post". Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

As others have found out, the hat is awarded for participating on a new site, which is actually a trigger we've used in the past (Winter Bash 2015's Explorer hat), which was ironically not even a secret hat. For those who like lists, the requirements for the hat were:

- Visit a site where you have *never* posted a question or answer before (even if it's been deleted).
- Post a new question or answer *during* Winter Bash.
- Get its score to at least 3.
- Wait until the post is 3 days old.
- The post cannot be deleted or community wiki, and if it's a question, it cannot be closed.

Comment: @Glorfindel If y'all haven't figured it out yet, most of the triggers were also reused, so it's not really spoiling, just figuring out which of the previous triggers are assigned to which hats. ;P

Comment: Wasn't there something in 2013 as well? I'm pretty sure I posted [this answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/1725/181) just to get a hat, though don't remember which now. (Might have required only posting, without waiting, etc)

Answer (score 1):

It just means "post a question or answer", but if you already *ever* posted a question on that site, further questions don't count (similarly for answers).

Note that only questions or answers posted *during this Winter Bash* count; this is true for all hats which reference a specific post. (E.g. you can still get a Cosmic Brain for a Nice Answer badge on an old post, because the hat references the 'badge', not the post.)

Comment: so it has to be the first Q or A of the day?

Comment: No, it has either to be your first Q *ever* on that site, or your first A *ever* on that site.

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza It's encouraging users to try out new sites... you have to pick a site you've not ever really used before (easiest if you don't even have an account there yet) and then post a question or answer that gets 3 upvotes.

Comment: so this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10491287/1380867 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/11053984/1380867 should get a + 3

Comment: @MoisesZaragoza no, because that answer wasn't posted during this Winter Bash.