# Is there a bug in the Mother of Dragons trigger?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2019

The secret hat 'Mother of Dragons'

[image]

has the following trigger:

> Create a first post (question or answer) that after 3 days is +3 or higher.

[More specifically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304919/295232):

> - Visit a site where you have *never* posted a question or answer before (even if it's been deleted).
>  - Post a new question or answer *during* Winter Bash.
>  - Get its score to at least 3.
>  - Wait until the post is 3 days old.
>  - The post cannot be deleted or community wiki, and if it's a question, it cannot be closed.

I have asked a question a week ago on Earth Science: [Does the geothermal activity influence the climate in Iceland?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/18699/2958) which was my [first post](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/12685) there, and I think it should qualify for the hat. Is there a bug in the trigger? It reminds me of [Why are there no review tasks generated for a couple of my recent First Posts on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327350/295232) Or did I post an question/answer before there and I just can't remember it anymore?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no bug in the trigger. There is a very small bug in the detailed description that you posted here, where according to this description you should earn the hat, but according to the exact definition you don't get it.

**Update**: as you guessed, it is a similar issue as to what happened on the [first posts on a site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327379/51) hat trigger.

Comment: OK. Now I'm wondering where in that description is room for a *small* bug ... And if animuson deliberately put it there ...

Comment: I don't think that it was deliberate. Only a power user like you would possibly even run into it. Required a very close reading of the sql and a minute of head scratching to figure out why you weren't getting it.

Comment: I take that as a compliment :)

Comment: I am left wondering. Will you tell us after WB completed what the small error in the description was?

Comment: Yeah, would be happy to

Comment: @glorfindel did I answer your question well enough to get an accept?

Comment: To be honest, no; I'd expect the full definition of the trigger (or at least a concrete pointer). But, since it's holiday season and you need it for one of the hats: here you go!

Comment: Happy New Year, and congratulations for [winning Winter Bash 2019 on Meta](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/meta.stackexchange.com)! See the bounty message, perhaps you could expand your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I agree that it was a design flaw, but it was not something that I was able to take care of at the time. If we ever reuse this hat or something like it, it will apply only to questions and answers.