# Let me know earlier that I can't award a bounty within the first 24 hours

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

I've just started a bounty [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340838/295232), and though the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/295232) states bounties can only be awarded 24 hours after starting them, this isn't immediately obvious and I have to confirm an IMPORTANT WARNING to discover it's not working after all:

[image: The first warning asks if the user is sure they want to award the bounty because the action can't be undone.]

[image: The following red error tooltip states the bounty can't be awarded for another 22 hours.]

Concrete proposal: there's a [tooltip for the '+100' link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7mlZ.png) which currently says:

> Click to award this answer your bounty worth 100 reputation

Can this be changed into something like

> You can award this answer your bounty worth 100 reputation in 22 hours

The link itself (which is [a lighter shade of blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd3JL.png) until you hover over or click it) could be made gray instead, to indicate that it's disabled right now. Like this:

[image]

Comment: @YaakovEllis FYA, [this exact request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78942/if-its-too-early-to-award-a-bounty-indicate-so-earlier) (in the form of bug report) was declined in the past.

Comment: That was a _looong_ time ago. I think that the request has merit. We'll see. And also - have you memorized every feature request in the system?

Comment: In mobile full-size version the button to award the bounty appears with grey colour but it's not clear if it becomes blueish or not when it's possible to award (no real base of comparison). Could have proper user feedback too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature has been implemented. When you add a bounty to a question, the button for awarding the bounty to an answer is now grayed out for 24 hours, with an appropriate tooltip message and cursor.

If anyone wants to see how it looks, I encourage you to add a bounty to this question.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that on mobile I can’t hover to see the tooltip and the color was not enough of an indicator. I mistook it for meaning the bounty hadn’t been awarded yet and was really confused about why the button wasn’t working until I got on the computer. Maybe it would be better to hide those buttons that no-one can do anything with instead of disable them? The time left before the bounty can be awarded could be included in the bounty notice.