# Without understandable feedback it's hard to know if I can reward my bounty

Tags: feature-request, design, bounties, mobile-web, responsive-design

This issue was reproduced in Android 10 using Google Chrome and using the browser in Desktop mode, and was reproduced in more than one community.

As you can see in the next image, I created a question and raised a bounty. Yet, when I clicked to reward the answer, nothing happened.

[image]

Many users (notably new users) know that a bounty cannot be rewarded in less than 24 hours. However, it's difficult to know this rule is what's blocking my action. As designed, users must know that when the bounty has that specific color, the bounty is not yet "rewardable."

Can we add a pop-up / snackbar when someone tries to reward a bounty too early informing the user of what's going on?

Comment: This is probably a side effect of [Let me know earlier that I can't award a bounty within the first 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341462/295232) – on mobile, you can't see the tooltip of course.

Comment: Yeah, this needs something other than just color to convey meaning.