# Access To a Review Queue I can't do anything with

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

On Stack Overflow I suddenly have access to a new review queue "Meta Reviews" even though I don't have the rep to do any reviews, is this intentional?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It isn't really different from the 'Meta Reviews' link on the [review page itself](https://stackoverflow/review). That is also shown regardless of whether you have actual access or not.

Comment: Yeah I just thought it was odd it appeared suddenly.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!